# Is there a way to upload a file through PHP with specific "tmp_name"?

Tags: php

When uploading a file through PHP - The default behavior of the interpreter is to save the file in a temporary folder, with temporary name.

Then we will have to use the function ***`move_uploaded_file()`*** in order to save it permanently.

If I have access to the php code- **is there a way to skip the** ***`move_uploaded_file()`*** **phase** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. You can specify which directory to put the temporary files in, but not decide on the temporary name yourself.

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory, unless another location has been given with the upload_tmp_dir directive in php.ini.

So you can set [upload_tmp_dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir):

> The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.
>
> If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.

However, this merely decides the directory but not the filename itself.

I think there is pretty solid reasoning why you can't do that:

1. Concurrency: How would you know if multiple users / multiple processes are trying to write to the same filename that your application logic decides on? This would cause a lot of race conditions if handled differently.
2. Depending on your operating system and filename escaping, it could also be a huge security risk to have the file named based on user input or application logic. For example, one could try to overwrite the password file `/etc/shadow` on a Linux-based system and hook into system access.

Furthermore, I personally don't really see any reason why using the process with `move_uploaded_file()` would be bothersome.

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks!